# Excel VBA : Recorrer Fila por Fila de la Ultima Columna

Tags: excel, vba, offset

se requiere obtener el resultado de la resta de las dos ultimas Columnas **(G-F)** esto lo realiza el siguiente Código (el escenario es que las columnas irán aumentando y el calculo solo se quedara la Columna G)¿hay forma de determinar ese rango para el recorrido?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub Operacion()
With Hoja1
Dim rng, cel as Range
ul = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("G2:G" & ul)
For Each cel in rng
cel.Replace ".",""

x = cel-cel.offset(,-1) 
cel.offset(,2) = x
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822